# R rChart plot would not display due to config.yml filepath slashes

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, rcharts, sankey-diagram

From the rChart package, dependencies are read in from the config.yml file, like so:

```
sankey:
  css: [css/sankey.css]
  jshead: [js/d3.v3.js,js/sankey.js]
  cdn:
    css:
      - "http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/css/sankey.css"
    jshead: 
      - "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"
      - "http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/js/sankey.js"
```

The problem is, when reading in the path, R seems to be having problems with front and backslashes and would not display the graph:

when inspecting the element of the plot in the web browesr, this is shown:

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<link href=dirPath\sankey/css/sankey.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dirPath\sankey/js/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dirPath\sankey/js/sankey.js"></script>

</head>
```

It seems like it appends the "\" automatically and that's what causing it not to be able to read in the dependencies.

Anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Can your provide your `sessionInfo()` so that I can investigate?